# Concurrency management for scaled services accessing DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, horizontal-scaling

Let's say we have a service exposing a REST endpoint (spring boot).

This endpoint allows for rating a product. You can re rate at any time.
What happens in this endpoint is checking if you rated before and update the final rating.

My question is regarding the situation when we have a million requests coming per second to this service we scaled horizontally to 100 instances.

This is the flow of actions so its easy to follow:

```
var userReview = getUserReviewFromDb(UserId, ProductId);
var numberOfReviews = getNumberOfReviewsForProductFromDb(ProductId);
if (userReview == null) {
  // user didn't priorly review product
  // here we calculate new score of product and persist it
  var newReview = addNewReview(UserRating, UserID, ProductId);
  var newRating = calculateNewRating(ProductId, numberOfReviews + 1, UserRating);
  persisteNewProductRating(ProductId, newRating);
  return newRating;
} else {
  var newRating = calculateNewRating(ProductId, numberOfReviews, UserRating, UserId);
  persisteNewProductRating(ProductId, newRating);
  return newRating;
}
```

So my question is, can we have issues where this code will be executed by many requests that would make the rating flawed ? since they all get a copy of number of previous previous in order to calculate new review. It seems obvious that we can, I wouldn't want to lock a full DB just but it seems like pretty much the only way, either that or send all requests in a transaction.

What are clean ways to manage this concurrency ? Im using Spring boot.

Comment: We could use Kafka with log compaction to save latest rating, then the listener could update db. Are there more ways ? Synchronous  maybe

Comment: Don't update the rating on every review.  Have a separate process recalculate ratings on a schedule (every 10 minutes, tune as needed) for all products that have had review since the last recalculation.  The review code shouldn't need to look at the current rating at all.

Comment: Makes sense for not recalculating review when user rates. I thought first we should return the new review but it won't happen. Im gonna use Kafka streams on a topic having log compaction (key is userId-productId, value is rating). Kafka streams will be used to get average of values. Will post a proper solution once I have it. What do you think @JimGarrison ?